# Accessing a possibly undefined system environment variable from LaTeX (followup question)

Tags: macros, programming, environment-variables

This question is a followup to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62010/can-i-access-system-environment-variables-from-latex-for-instance-home) in which @egreg provided a command `\getenv` to access a system environment variable.   In response to my comment, he suggested a way to expand his script so that it would deal with the possibility that the environment variable was not defined.
I believe I've followed his suggestion in the script below, and 
expected the `\getenv` command in the body of the email to return  UNDEFINED, but it returns empty.    Could you please explain how to get it to do so?   Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{catchfile}
    \newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
      \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{}%
      \ifx\temp\empty\def\temp{UNDEFINED}\fi
      \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
    \begin{document}
        test \getenv{NOT_DEFINED}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added `\ifx\temp\empty\def\temp{UNDEFINED}\fi` to the wrong code in the linked answer.

The comment was “Add before the `\if\relax` lines…” and so this was referring to the most recent version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{catchfile}
  \newcommand\getenv[2][]{%
    \immediate\write18{kpsewhich --var-value #2 > \jobname.tmp}%
    \CatchFileDef{\temp}{\jobname.tmp}{\endlinechar=-1}%
    \ifx\temp\empty\def\temp{UNDEFINED}\fi
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
\else
  \ifluatex
    \newcommand\getenv[2][]{%
      \edef\temp{\directlua{tex.sprint(
        kpse.var_value("\luatexluaescapestring{#2}") or "" ) }}%
      \ifx\temp\empty\def\temp{UNDEFINED}\fi
      \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
  \else
    \usepackage{catchfile}
    \newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
      \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{\endlinechar=-1}%
      \ifx\temp\empty\def\temp{UNDEFINED}\fi
      \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
  \fi
\fi

\begin{document}

\getenv{SHELL}

\getenv{NOT_DEFINED}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the `\endlinechar=-1` part in the `\CatchFileDef` lines, that remove the unwanted end-of-line character. You may need to use

```
\immediate\write18{rm -f \jobname.tmp;kpsewhich --var-value #2 > \jobname.tmp}
```

with XeTeX, depending on your shell setup.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `\typeout{\temp}` you will see that `\temp` is equal to `\par`, so rather than testing for `\empty` you need to test for `\par`. A simple `\ifx\temp\par` does not work but thanks to [Why can't I compare a string with \par?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64084/why-cant-i-compare-a-string-with-par/64092?s=1|7.3233#64092), the following does:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\def\apar{\par}
\newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{}%
  \ifx\temp\apar\def\temp{UNDEFINED}\fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
\begin{document}
    test \getenv{NOT_DEFINED}
\end{document}
```