# Compare two macros as strings in LaTeX (e-TeX)

Tags: macros, environments, etoolbox, environment-variables, comparison

#### How do I compare two macros that are one-expansion away from being strings?

```
\def\A{ICT}
\newgetenv[\ICT]{\A}
% `\newgetenv` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184924
```

Now I want to check if whatever `\ICT` evaluates to is simply what `\A` evaluates to; i.e.: `"ICT"`.

Attempts (one line at a time; others commented):

```
\ifdefequal{\expandafter\ICT}{\expandafter\A}{\def\ICT{FOO}}{\def\ICT{BAR}}
\ifdefequal{\ICT}{\expandafter\A}{\def\ICT{FOO}}{\def\ICT{BAR}}
\ifdefequal{\expandafter\ICT}{\A}{\def\ICT{FOO}}{\def\ICT{BAR}}
```

I've also tried the same 3 possibilities with `\ifcsequal` and `\ifdefstring`. Also tried giving up on the `\A` and just using: `ICT` verbatim.

But they all define an `\ICT` with a value of `BAR`, no matter what I set my `$ICT` system environment variable to.

Comment: Just a guess, have you checked the **xstring** package?

Comment: It's hard to guess what you expect the `\expandafter` to do in those situations. They will just expand into the internal definition of `ifdefequal`   don't you just want `\ifx\A\ICT yes \else no\fi` ?

Comment: `\newgetenv` from one of my answers apparently...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes there is a link to your answer in the comment in the code (not the most helpful place to have it but it is there)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I saw that -- didn't remember the answer and I am not sure it's helpful at all (I mean the answer)

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments of code

Comment: @ChristianHupfer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375535/environment-variable-def-if-defined-else-def-default#comment929367_375535

Comment: I've tried with `\IfStrEq` from the xstring pacakge and `\ifx`. Neither worked. I've got [this test-case repository](https://github.com/AlecTaylor/latex-env-testcase), but I'm not sure how to resolve the `\input` macro (which isn't recognised). Trying to find what package to `\usepackage` for…

Comment: What about `\pdfstrcmp` ?

Answer (score 1):

Making a usable test file...

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xstring}%
\usepackage{catchfile}%

\newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
%\getenv[\INCLUDE]{\string INCLUDE}

\def\newtemp{}%
\newcommand{\newgetenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{}%
  \StrGobbleRight{\temp}{1}[\newtemp]%  Delete the trailing whitespace character
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\edef#1{\newtemp}\fi%
}%

\begin{document}

\def\A{ICT}
\newgetenv[\ICT]{\A}

\ifx\ICT\A
\def\ICT{BAR}
\else
\def\ICT{FOO}
\fi

\show\ICT

\end{document}
```

by default defines `\ICT` as `FOO`

```
 pdflatex pp024
```

produces

```
> \ICT=macro:
->FOO.
l.32 \show\ICT
```

But if the environment variable ICT has value ICT (which appears to be the test that you were trying to implement, although you do not say) then `\ICT` is defined as `BAR`.

```
 ICT=ICT pdflatex pp024
```

produces

```
> \ICT=macro:
->BAR.
```

---

A much simpler definition is

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\def\A{ICT}

\ifx\ICT\A
\def\ICT{BAR}
\else
\def\ICT{FOO}
\fi

\show\ICT

\end{document}
```

where

```
pdflatex \\def\\ICT{$ICT}\\input pp024
```

produces

```
> \ICT=macro:
->FOO.
```

unless ICT=ICT when you get

```
 ICT='ICT' ;pdflatex \\def\\ICT{$ICT}\\input pp024
```

which produces

```
> \ICT=macro:
->BAR.
```

Comment: Actually I was testing if `ICT` environment variable was defined. When it's not defined, for some reason it gets the verbatim `ICT` text. I'm using `latexmk` to build my LaTeX project, within a regular `Makefile`. Your code did not work in this setup.

Comment: @AT The code is pure tex code so will work the same way whether tex is called from the command line or from latexmk or a makefile. the form setting the environment variable on the same line is bash syntax but there is no requirement to set the variable in that way, just set it however you wish.

Comment: Hmm, well does it matter if `\newgetenv[`; `\ifx`; is in the prelude (before `\begin{document}`)?

Comment: @AT probably not, but you've posted two questions on this now and still not shown a reproducible example of what you are doing or what error you get.

Comment: Using your exact code example, and it doesn't work. `pdflatex example0.tex`; `> \ICT=macro:
->FOO.` and running `export ICT=foo` beforehand still gives same output.

Comment: @AT yes as written it does just what you asked and shows FOO unless you export ICT=ICT when it shows BAR

Comment: It only every shows `FOO` for me. I should highlight my first comment: [Expectation] when `ICT` environment variable isn't defined: fallback to default value.

Comment: @AT I suggest you fix the question as I can not reconcile what the question asks "Now I want to check if whatever \ICT evaluates to is simply what \A evaluates to; i.e.: "ICT"."  with what you ask in comments. The posted answer addresses the posted question, it does not test for anything being undefined or empty. Perhaos you simply want to change the code to have `\def\A{}` so it tests against empty but I really can not guess.